# What's Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client and Why is it Taking Over My Computer?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

During some application process or another, I was forcefully encouraged to download and install Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client. After canceling the installation, future installations of a lot of things had to choke and regroup because the Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client was not complete. So, I completed it.

Now it looks like every time Microsoft wants to update it, it creates a new directory in my root named with random letters and numbers (like C:\2e3351403f03ef508fd46552fe1325). Each of these directories has sub-directories 1025-3082 with a eula file, LocalizedData, and SetupResources.dll. Then there are also other subdirectories and files. I kinda suspect these are installation resources and do not need to remain on my computer.

What's up with this? What's Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client and Why is it Taking Over My Computer? Can I delete the directories? Are there any consequences to uninstalling .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

Basically, .Net is a interpretor/just in time compiler package for some programming languages which Microsoft promotes. If you don't have it, programs written in the won't work.

Version 4 happens to be the newest version of .Net. It isn't necessary for normal operation of your computer, but many programs use it, so it's a good idea to have it installed. Please note that new versions don't include old versions! Don't be surprised if it happens that you need to install version 2 for some program.

The directories which show up are temporary directories used by the installation which are supposed to be deleted after installation completes. I usually delete them by hand, when they don't disappear.

Comment: If you have .NET3.0 or .NET3.5 installed, then you also have .NET2.0 as these versions are built using the same CLR. .NET4.0 introduces a new CLR and as such is a separate entity.